# In Django, when a function in views.py returns a JsonResponse, how can it render a web page at the same time?

Tags: javascript, python, django, ajax

I am trying to write a webpage in Django that obtains real-time input from the user and gives some responses back to the user. However, when the function in views.py returns a type of JsonResponse, my HTML file in the template cannot be showed properly. How can I fix this issue？

My HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Real-time Input Text</title>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <input type="text" id="input-box">
  <div id="output"></div>

  <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
      $("#input-box").on("input", function() {
        var inputText = $(this).val(); // Get the current value of the input box

        $.ajax({
          url: "/update_text/",
          method: "POST",
          data: {
            text: inputText
          },
          success: function(response) {
            $("#output").text(response);
          }
        });
      });
    });
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

My function in views:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import JsonResponse

def update_text(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        text = request.POST.get("text", "")

        return JsonResponse(text, safe=False)
    else:
        return JsonResponse({}, status=400)
```

Comment: That makes no sense. Why do you want to return two different types of responses from the same endpoint?

Answer (score 1):

Rendering a template is not possible with `JsonResponse`.

You can check the request headers, particularly the `accept` header. and if is `application/json` then return the `JsonResponse`, otherwise return `render(...)`.

```py
def update_text(request):
    if request.accepts('application/json'):
       return JsonResponse(..)
    else:
       return render(..)
```

Answer (score 0):

You should return render and pass your data as context

```
return render(request, template_name, context)
```